# In unity is there a system about if player drops perfect increase score much more

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my game my player is a square.If you touch the screen its jumping and rotating depending on how much do you press the screen and i have score system. I want to make a game mechanic about if square drops perfectly after jumping gain much more score. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Anyone knows???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put an if statement whenever the square touches the ground, the if statement then will check if the square has a perfect rotation.